# importarange with a link inside the cell

Tags: google-docs

I need to use an importrange in which references to the range are stored in cells. I tried to find information on the Internet and found this, but it doesn't work.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1BEVzr3befehzTRvj0xAeOrsIaScBrTbeiciAxsTbCJY"; "'list1'!"&A1&":"&A2&"")
```

Please tell me how it should be

Comment: Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It suddenly started working with such a formula. It's not clear why it didn't work at first, and then it became, but okay